# Changing background color of a QWidget is not possible with a css class and setProperty()

Tags: css, qt, pyqt4

In a sublclass of a QWidget:

```
class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        ...
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

works just fine with this css:

```
QWidget {
    background-color: black;
}
```

but adding this:

```
self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
self.setProperty('class', 'main')
```

and changing the css to:

```
QWidget.main {
    background-color: black;
}
```

shows no effect at all. What am i missing on this one? setProperty works like a charm on other Objects.

Comment: strange, in normal Qt it is working for me.

Comment: Try to call default paint method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subclass a custom widget from QWidget, then in order to use the StyleSheets you need to provide a paintEvent to the custom widget. See [this page](http://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget).

So add the following method to your `MainWidget` class:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    "Reimplementation of paintEvent to allow for style sheets"
    opt = QtGui.QStyleOption()
    opt.initFrom(self)
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    self.style().drawPrimitive(QtGui.QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)
    painter.end()
```

Comment: May i bother you giving me a similar answer for a `QPushButton` because changeing the line in `paintEvent` to `self.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt, painter, self)`  turns a button invisible

Comment: What happens if you leave it as `QtGui.QStyle.PE_Widget` for the push button as well? A QPushButton inherits from a QWidget after all.

Comment: That was my first try but it showed unexpected behaviour. For example the font settings were gone. I will need to make sure that the issue is not in another place.

Comment: OK: The css itself turned out to be flawed. The above reimplementation of `paintEvent` is only needed when subclassing QWidget.